# Replacing an Interface or Abstract Class with a Single Class and Enum Parameter (Kotlin)

Tags: oop, generics, kotlin

I would like to call a single class with an `enum` parameter and let the `Types` and `collections<Type>` of the class-members be contingent on this `enum` parameter.  I'm willing to accept an answer that this is exactly the purpose of abstract classes and interfaces and there is no other way to proceed along these lines.  I just want to be sure I'm not missing a clever trick.

For example, I wanted to represent a collection of movie frames as arrays of bytes or arrays of shorts where image processing is contingent on the channel-depth of color and the bit-depth.  I believe the standard practice would be to create an abstract class or an interface and then inherit from those for each of the `enum` members.  This standard solution requires multiple files and separates the processing specifics into those separate files.

The following class illustrates the attempt without interface or abstract class.  The problem is that anything entering or exiting from this class has type `Any` and has to be explicitly cast.  That is a non-starter.  I'm not familiar enough with Generics to see if that provides a solution.  There is `Type` erasure in JVM so I think that is also a dead end.  My example is Kotlin, but I think it follows also for other object-oriented languages.

```
class MovieFrames(val nRow:Int,val nCol:Int, val type: ElementType) {
  val list = mutableListOf<Any>()
  val frameSize = nRow * nCol
  fun nframe() = list.size

  constructor(nRow: Int, nCol: Int, values: List<Any>, type: ElementType = ElementType.Gray8) :
        this(nRow, nCol, type) {
    when (type) {
        ElementType.RGB8 -> values.forEach { list.add(it as ByteArray) }
        ElementType.Gray8 -> values.forEach { list.add(it as ByteArray) }
        ElementType.Gray16 -> values.forEach { list.add(it as ShortArray) }
    }

  }

  fun saveToFile(filename: String) {
    when (type) {
        ElementType.RGB8 -> {/*put Red, Green, Blue bytes to disk*/ }
        ElementType.Gray8 -> {/*put Bytes to disk*/ }
        ElementType.Gray16 -> {/*put Bytes to disk with specific byte ordering*/ }
    }
  }

  fun getFrame(f:Int) : Any {
    return list[f]
    }
}

enum class ElementType(bitDepth: Int, channels: Int) {
  RGB8(8, 3),
  Gray8(8, 1),
  Gray16(16, 1);
}
```

Comment: Enums are objects. They can have behaviors. Instead of performing a behavior based on the value (`when`), have the enum object perform the behavior. For example, the enums could define `create(...)` which handles the construction logic `values.forEach { list.add(it as ByteArray) }`, and a `saveToFile(...)` for the saving logic. This approach is more object oriented, as the enum objects are now in charge of the behaviors that depend on said enum objects. If I'm misunderstanding your question, please let me know.

Comment: The question is not clear and the terminology is also non standard that you are using. To answer your question would be a mix of rewriting your code, and teaching you a fair amount.  Learn about generics, object-oriented design, what should have the responsibility for what action, and more.  Otherwise we are doing your work for you to an extent that is outside the scope of a question, which is basically "rewrite this to make it work for me."

Comment: I think Vince Emigh's solution is what I would do too.  Does that give you enough information you need to proceed?  Something else you might want to consider, which is specific to Kotlin, is using [sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html), which are basically an extension of enums.

Comment: Maybe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ or https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better sight for non-specific questions like this.

Comment: @JaysonMinard when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat sure, but tell him that, not me. I'm not providing warnings about everything silly and bad someone could do given otherwise good advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions and encouragement.  From Yoni Gibbs' comment, Sealed Classes was the "trick" I was seeking, that is some combination of Enum and Polymorphism.  In regards to Generics, it took two `Types` to encapsulate the underling storage object and how the pixels are represented. Here is the result that combines all the suggestions.

```
//e.g. T=ByteArray, ShortArray
//e.g. E=Byte,Short
sealed class Frames<T,E>(val nrow:Int,val ncol:Int,val bitDepth:Int,val channelDepth:Int) {
  val size=nrow*ncol //frame size
  abstract val list:MutableList<T>
  fun totalBytes() = list.size*size*bitDepth/8*channelDepth
  abstract fun set(i:Int,data:E)
  abstract fun get(i:Int): E

  fun saveToDisk(filename:String)=saveByteArray(filename,toByteArray())
    abstract fun toByteArray(isSmallEndian:Boolean=false):ByteArray
  }

class Gray8Frame(nrow:Int,ncol:Int) :
    Frames<ByteArray,Byte>(nrow,ncol,8,1) {
  override val list= mutableListOf<ByteArray>()
  override fun set(i: Int,data:Byte) {list[i/size][i%size]=data}
  override fun get(i: Int)=list[i/size][i%size]
  override fun toByteArray(isSmallEndian: Boolean)
        = ByteArray(totalBytes()){get(it)}
}
class Gray16Frame(nrow:Int,ncol:Int) :
    Frames<ShortArray,Short>(nrow,ncol,16,1) {
  override val list= mutableListOf<ShortArray>()
  override fun set(i: Int,data:Short) {list[i/size][i%size]=data}
  override fun get(i: Int)=list[i/size][i%size]
  override fun toByteArray(isSmallEndian: Boolean)
        = list.flatMap { it.toByteList() }.toByteArray() 
        //implement short-->List<Byte>
}

class RGBFrame(nrow:Int,ncol:Int) :
    Frames<ByteArray,List<Byte>>(nrow,ncol,8,3) {
  override val list= mutableListOf<ByteArray>()
  override fun set(i: Int,data:List<Byte>) {
    list[i/size][3*i%size+0]=data[0]//Red
    list[i/size][3*i%size+1]=data[1]//Green
    list[i/size][3*i%size+2]=data[2]//Blue
  }
  override fun get(i: Int)=listOf(
    list[i/size][3*i%size+0],//Red
    list[i/size][3*i%size+1],//Green
    list[i/size][3*i%size+2] //Blue
  )
  override fun toByteArray(isSmallEndian: Boolean)
        = list.flatMap { it.asList() }.toByteArray()
  }

fun saveByteArray(filename:String, byteArray: ByteArray) { } //save bytes here
```